# laptop shuts down due to overheating during ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, shutdown, overheating

I have an HP pavilion g6 laptop and it came pre-installed with windows 8.

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu. I've disabled secure boot and tried to install both Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04.

During both installations my laptop shut down and later when I started it again it warned about an overheating problem. even during the installation the laptop fan blew at a very high speed.

AMD A4, 4 GB RAM, 1GB ati radeon 7420G,500GB

Answer (score 1):

Try blowing the vents clear with canned air and perhaps working in a cooler environment. This should help with the overheating problem which is extremely likely to be the root cause of your difficulties.